# C# All Check-box Appearance

Tags: c#, checkbox, custom-controls

In my WinForms Visual Studio application i have a checkbox styled as a Flat Button with this C# code:

```
 private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TestBox.Checked == true)
        {
            TestBox.Image = Image.FromFile("M:\\CheckBox_52x.png");
            TestBox.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            TestBox.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            // make all four (!) BackColors transparent!
            TestBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            TestBox.FlatAppearance.CheckedBackColor = Color.Transparent;
            TestBox.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.Transparent;

        }
        else
        {
            TestBox.Image = Image.FromFile("M:\\CheckBoxUncheck_52x.png");
            TestBox.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            TestBox.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            // make all four (!) BackColors transparent!
            TestBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Cyan;
            TestBox.FlatAppearance.CheckedBackColor = Color.Cyan;
            TestBox.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.Cyan;
        }
    }
```

I was wondering, if instead of doing this to every single checkbox in my application, can i make the "UNCHECKED" version i have coded the default checkbox style for this applicatiom - eg - every time i create a new one it appears with these properties.

Please keep in mind that i am brand new to coding in C#.

Comment: So is this Windows Forms? Do you have multiple forms? Are you asking whether you need to have multiple *methods* like this? (If you change your code to use `sender` instead of hard-coding it to `TestBox` you can use the same event handler for all the checkboxes - was that what you meant?)

Comment: Yes, there are multiple forms within the application.

What i'm trying to say is, i want the Flat-Button-Borderless Checkbox with the Unchecked image to appear the same way over every single form. 
Same goes for the checked version.

So i do not have to do this piece of code over and over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want multiple controls to use the same eventhandler, that's easy - just use the same event handler. Change your code to something like:

```
private void HandleCheckBoxCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) sender;
    string imageFile;
    Color color;
    if (checkBox.Checked == true)
    {
        // TODO: Use resources embedded within your app
        imageFile = "M:\\CheckBox_52x.png";
        color = Color.Transparent;
    }
    else
    {
        imageFile = "M:\\CheckBoxUncheck_52x.png";
        color = Color.Cyan;
    }
    // TODO: Load each file once and reuse the bitmap, I suspect.
    checkBox.Image = Image.FromFile(imageFile);
    checkBox.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    checkBox.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
    checkBox.BackColor = color;
    checkBox.FlatAppearance.CheckedBackColor = color;
    checkBox.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = color;
}
```

You can then attach the same handler to all your checkboxes.

If you have multiple classes, you could make that a public static method. At that point you may need to add the event handler in code rather than getting the designer to do it - I don't know whether the designer knows how to use static methods for event handlers. But it would just be something like:

```
TestBox.CheckedChanged += CheckBoxUtilities.HandleCheckBoxCheckedChanged;
```

That's if you really just want the same code to be used for event handlers. Other things to consider are:

- Constructing a subclass of `CheckBox` as suggested by rakatherock. My own experience with creating custom controls in Windows Forms has not been great, but from an OO perspective it feels fine. An initial implementation could just derive from `CheckBox` and implicitly add an event handler which does exactly what your current code does.
- If you want to find all the `CheckBox` controls in a form at some point, you can use the `Controls` property and then recurse through any control which itself a container. I won't go into the details of that now though, as it sounds like you don't really want this - unless you did it just to find all the `CheckBox` controls and add the same event handler to all of them.

Comment: Hi Jon, using this method Image "does not exist in current context" and ImageFile "use of unassigned local variable"

Comment: @Krono: Those were both just from a typo - fixed now. I'd strongly urge to to make sure you actually understand the code you're copying and pasting before using it though - in this case, I suspect you could have worked out the typo for yourself.

Comment: This is a possible solution but I think I would prefer to separate concerns: The styling and the data entry should go into separate methods. So I would put all the styling code into a function StyleMyCheckBox(CheckBox cbx, ..) and I would call it in the CheckChanged event.

Comment: @TaW: So you'd have a `CheckChanged` event handler that does nothing but call `StyleMyCheckBox`? You'd still want to have a single event handler method that does that, IMO - it's just an extract method refactoring replacing the whole of a method body with a call to another method. I'm not saying it's bad, but I don't see that it really separates concerns.

Comment: I know nothing about what other data processing is supposed to be happening; that is all up to the OP. But one advantage you get is that you can also use it for initially setting up the states. Another is that each CheckBox could still do its own data processing. If we all lump it together we need to cast the sender etc.. Still, largely a matter of taste and the details we don't know..

Comment: @TaW: I wouldn't suggest adding any extra logic in that method - if other things need to happen in response to the same event, they can happen in  other event handlers. It's not like you can only attach one handler per event.

Comment: @JonSkeet people often argue past this point and forget it when discussing one handler per many events ;)

Comment: Whoops, @Jon, our comments have crossed; I didn't really notice that you were suggesting a new handler and read a little sloppily that your code goes into the original CheckChanged handler. Nor __who__ posted it ;-) - So I guess the idea is OK, but imo the name somewhat poor as it says nothing about the real purpose. I still prefer having a styling function. And I still love your books ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by creating custom checkbox control.

Comment: Please bear in mind, as i am completely new to all of this, how do i do such a thing?

Comment: https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiDzZPFtNbLAhUMOJoKHaNWDcoQtwIIHTAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dpd-S6UoQHh8&usg=AFQjCNFU-0aTrukn5Fn9OlW5_4tQJBcn3w&sig2=oTVtKavr2M4m-P8CO0U_NA

Answer (score 1):

From the question what you are trying to do is to manipulate all check boxes in the application from a single check box so here the logic goes like:

Save the All checkbox value(Checked or unchecked) in the settings

To create a settings value

```
Right Click Project>Properties>Settings>Give Name as someBoolValue,type as bool,Scope as User
```

So on CheckChanged event of this check box save the value in Settings variable that we have created just now.In CheckChangedEvent of main All Check box code goes like:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.someBoolValue=cbCheckBox.Checked;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Now on every form load are where ever the event is suitable do like

```
foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
{
   if(c is CheckBox)
   {
     c.Checked=Properties.Settings.Default.someBoolValue
   }
}
```

Note:You can replace all the check box that i implemented with your custom controls.I have given you just an idea how to do it.